# Check if I have Displayport 1.2

Tags: displayport

I have a Thinkpad Yoga S1 ( https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/s1_yoga_ug_en.pdf ) and would like to know if I have a DisplayPort 1.1 or 1.2.

I'm running Linux and Win10 on it. Can someone tell me, how I can check it?

Comment: ? It doesn’t have a DisplayPort connector at all, as stated in the manual.

Comment: it does, it's here physically. It's the user guide, that's why it might not be shown. I couldn't find any specifications sheet from Lenovo.

Comment: The only mention in the user guide is of a DisplayPort connector on the OneLink Dock.

Comment: the machine is in front of me and there is a DisplayPort. I have no Idea why lenovo doesn't mention it in the User Guide. I'm asking for a solution I can apply on my notebook so I know what version I have.

Comment: You will have to post the model/version number for the S1 if you want us to help